# Convert list comprehension to for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, huffman-code

On [this Huffman code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), I found the below code.

```
heap = [[wt, [sym, ""]] for sym, wt in symb2freq.items()]
```

Is that possible to convert this kind of list compression into a for-loop?

Comment: yes, it's possible

Comment: And what do you want the output to be?

Comment: `heap = []
for sym, wt in symb2freq.items():
 heap.append([wt, [sym, ""]])`

Comment: @DanielRoseman the output will be a  list of lists of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
heap = []
for sym, wt in symb2freq.items():
    heap.append([wt, [sym, ""]])
```

Comment: @N Chauhan append takes one argument, right?

Comment: Yep. It adds the item given to the end of the list.

Comment: Perfect, I got it.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

`heap = [[wt, [sym, ""]] for sym, wt in enumerate(symb2freq.items())]`

Comment: This doesn't give the same result and is still a list comprehension...